# linux - Checking for installed packages and if found remove

Tags: package, debian, apt-get, dpkg

I'm working with python and I need to check for installed packages and if installed remove them.

I already did the opposite:

```
dpkg -l | grep -qw package || apt-get install package
```

Help! :/

PS: I use Debian destribution on raspberry pi.

Thanks,
Luís Ferreira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
dpkg -l | grep -qw package && apt-get remove --purge package
```

The `||` operator in your original post means what follows will only run if the grep command doesn't find anything, while the `&&` operator in this command means that what follows will only run if the grep command *does* find something.

You can also leave out the --purge if you don't want to delete the application's configuration files...more on that [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/187891).